# Download complete map (highway,ways) of Pakistan and complete nodes from overpass-turbo.eu in geojson format

Tags: node.js, postgresql, openstreetmap

**I am not a native english speaker so please ignore my mistakes.**

I want to download complete map (highway,ways) of Pakistan and complete nodes from overpass-turbo in geojson format.

I already downloaded one city data but when I went to download complete country map, it gave me a error.

**Here how I download one city.**

1.I select a area form overpass-turbo and select highway and type = way just before run a query which is shown below
[image]

2. When I click on **build and run query**, after a while it looks like

[image]

3.So Data is ready for export, when I click on export it gives me option to download data as a geojson extension type which is..

[image]

4. I downloaded and used my data,

**NOW problem is that when I go to download complete country data it gives me error which is** 
[image]

I also increases query time but I don't know what is the problem.

Please help me to solve this problem.

**Link where I am downloading map**

https://overpass-turbo.eu/

Answer (score 0):

Overpass API is the wrong source for downloading complete countries. Overpass API can be used for downloading small data extracts. All highways of a specific country are probably just too much.

As an alternative use a [country or area extract](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Country_and_area_extracts). Afterwards [filter the data for specific tags](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_file_formats#Filter_for_specific_tags) by using the [tags-filter](https://docs.osmcode.org/osmium/latest/osmium-tags-filter.html) option from [osmium-tool](https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/). Alternative software for filtering are osmosis and osmfilter.

The following osmium command should extract all ways with a highway tag from the raw data you downloaded:

```
osmium tags-filter -o highways.osm.pbf pakistan.osm.pbf w/highway
```

Comment: #scai Can u please elaborate with an example?

Comment: The documentation of osmium-tags-filter contains examples. According to this documentation the following command should work: `osmium tags-filter -o highways.osm.pbf pakistan.osm.pbf w/highway`.

Comment: #scai I am facing trouble when I am running osmium command, it gives error that it is not recognised as internal or external command, I am using windows 10. Please Help ME.  Thanks

Comment: Please consider asking at https://github.com/osmcode/osmium-tool/issues or any of the OSM contact channels: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Contact_channels